# Extracting value of author <class > id property

Tags: applescript

I am trying get the author id from a tweet in the Mac Twitter app.

```
tell application "Twitter"
properties of item 3 of status of (home timeline of account 1)
end tell
```

[image]

```
tell application "Twitter"
author of item 3 of status of (home timeline of account 1)
end tell
```

[image]

How can I isolate "128938832" ?

SOLUTION: Chris from the AppleScript-Users mailing list just answered my question. The author property has a user id property. `user id of author of item 3 of status of (home timeline of account 1)` returns "128938832".

Answer (score 1):

I don't have Twitter, but if there aren't terms to get the ID of the author, you could probably cheat by forcing an error and extract the number from the error message, for example:

```
tell application "Twitter" to try
    (author of item 3 of status of (home timeline of account 1)) as number -- force error
on error errmess -- extract info from the error message
    set here to (offset of quote in errmess) + 1 -- first quote
    set there to here + (offset of quote in (text here thru -1 of errmess)) - 2 -- second quote
    set authorID to text here thru there of errmess
end try
```

Comment: Thanks Red, great sidestep ! I will accept that at the end of the day if I don't receive a "proper" answer. +1